# php - trying to print some special characters

Tags: php, echo

I have been trying to print some characters on my php page and it returns something else, like corrupted characters

like

> "joão", ø, ç, etc

```
echo '<br>não<br>'
```

the return is

```
nÃ£o
```

instead:

```
não
```

is this a problem with econding utf-8?

i have tried this code

```
header('Content-Type: text/html, charset=utf-8');
```

but no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your Content-Type header. It's `...; charset=...` with a *semicolon*.

Comment: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset-utf-8');?

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: that worked, but if i need to print some chinese characters, there is some global enconding?

Comment: Since you're using UTF-8, that is a "global" encoding which supports Chinese. If your file is saved as UTF-8 and you're setting the above header, `echo "漢字";` works just fine.

Comment: damn, it realy works, thanks m8, cant give correct asnwer yet, i must wait 5 min :p

Comment: I'll recommend you this for further details: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 1):

> Note: Your header `header('Content-type: text/html, charset=utf-8');`,
>   is the correct `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Your document (*php-file*) should be saved in *utf8 (without bom)* or use `iso-8859-1` instead of `utf8`

---

To save the document in utf8 without boom use notepade++ (select "Convert to utf-8 without BOM"):
[image]

or use:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

**Tip (if you are using database):**

If your database is UTF-8, then:

- php file converted to utf-8 without bom
- set header to utf8 `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

If your database is latin1, then:

- php file converted to ANSI
- set header to iso-8859-1`header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');`

Comment: deceze solution works fine, but i will try your solution too :p, thanks :)

Comment: I edited my answer, I added some tips on database and *charset*

Comment: i hate on thing on stackoverflow, i can only select one correct answer, deceze was faster, but i like you answer too :p it must have "text/html;" on your code

Comment: What matters is that we can help you and that my tips on database and "charsets" be useful in the future you.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your PHP source file is encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

Answer (score -2):

The encoding of your php file itself may be wrong. You might want to change it to utf-8.

However, it is not good practice to include special characters directly in your code. Instead, use the HTML charcode equivalents to produce valid output.

**Example**

```
echo 'n&atilde;o';
```

A comprehensive list of HTML character codes can be found [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Comment: -1 There's nothing wrong whatsoever with using "special characters" (what's so "special"?!) directly. It's only annoying to work with a page full of entities.

Comment: I assumed it was bad practice. Perhaps a remnant from earlier days where output in some browsers didn't work out for german characters?

Comment: A remnant from earlier days where Unicode wasn't very widely supported, especially by the authoring tools, and/or nobody knew how to handle encodings correctly.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing it up. !Thanks for the useless downvote.

Comment: its only for study porpouses, but if i had a big page would be a pain in the ass :P, thanks anywya ^^